# Puma sleeps an important thread on boot of rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I am running Rails 3 with Ruby 2.3.3 on puma with postgresql. I have an initializer/twitter.rb file that starts a thread on boot with a streaming api for twitter. When I use `rails server` to start my application, the twitter streaming works and I can reach my website like normal. (If I do not put the streaming on a different thread, the streaming works but I can not view my application in the browser since the thread is blocked by the twitter stream). But when I use `puma -C config/puma.rb` to start my application, I get the following message that is telling me that my thread was found on startup and was put to sleep. How can I tell puma to let me run this thread in the background on startup?

initializer/twitter.rb

```
### START TWITTER THREAD ### if production

if Rails.env.production?
  puts 'Starting Twitter Stream...'
  Thread.start {
    twitter_stream.user do |object|
      case object
        when Twitter::Tweet
          handle_tweet(object)
        when Twitter::DirectMessage
          handle_direct_message(object)
        when Twitter::Streaming::Event
          puts "Received Event: #{object.to_yaml}"
        when Twitter::Streaming::FriendList
          puts "Received FriendList: #{object.to_yaml}"
        when Twitter::Streaming::DeletedTweet
          puts "Deleted Tweet: #{object.to_yaml}"
        when Twitter::Streaming::StallWarning
          puts "Stall Warning: #{object.to_yaml}"
        else
          puts "It's something else: #{object.to_yaml}"
      end
    end
  }
end
```

config/puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'


on_worker_boot do
  # Valid on Rails up to 4.1 the initializer method of setting `pool` size
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
    Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

Message on startup

```
2017-04-19T23:52:47.076636+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2017-04-19T23:52:47.115595+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting Twitter Stream...
2017-04-19T23:52:47.229203+00:00 app[web.1]: Received FriendList: --- !ruby/array:Twitter::Streaming::FriendList []
2017-04-19T23:52:47.865735+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:13734
2017-04-19T23:52:47.865830+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot:
2017-04-19T23:52:47.865870+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] ! #<Thread:0x007f4df8bf6240@/app/config/initializers/twitter.rb:135 sleep> - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/buffering.rb:125:in `sysread'
2017-04-19T23:52:47.875056+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 0 (pid: 7) booted, phase: 0
2017-04-19T23:52:47.865919+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-04-19T23:52:47.882759+00:00 app[web.1]: [4] - Worker 1 (pid: 11) booted, phase: 0
2017-04-19T23:52:48.148831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Thanks in advance for the help. I have looked at several other posts mentioning `WARNING: Detected 1 Thread(s) started in app boot` but the answers say to ignore the warning if the thread is not important. In my case, the thread is very important and I need this thread to not sleep.

Comment: Update: I learned what a sleeping thread really is and that is not the issue. However, I am unsure of where to start my twitter stream thread. Should it stay in the initializer? Should I use a separate process (background app)? Should I start up the twitter stream on every puma worker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I think you have a bigger issue on your hands than a sleeping thread... which I guess might be caused by the fact that some things are misnamed and others are just not often considered when relying on a web framework.

In the world of servers, "workers" refer to `fork`ed processes that perform server related tasks, often accepting new connections and handling web requests.

**BUT** - `fork` *doesn't* duplicate threads! - **the new process (the worker) starts with only one single thread, which is a copy of the thread that called `fork`**.

This is because **processes don't share memory** (normally). Whatever global data you have in a process is private to that process (i.e., if you save connected websocket clients in an array, that array is different for each "worker").

This can't be helped, it's part of how the OS and `fork` are designed.

So, the warning is not something you can circumvent - it's an indication of a design flaw in the app(!).

For example, in your current design (assuming the thread wasn't sleeping), the `handle_tweet` method will only be called for the original server process and it won't be called for any worker process.

If you're using pub/sub, you only need one `twitter_stream` connection for the whole app (no matter how many servers or workers you application has) - perhaps a `twitter_stream` process (or background app) will be better than a thread.

But if you're implementing `handle_tweet` in a process specific way - i.e., by sending a message to every connected clients saved in an array - you need to make sure every "worker" initiates a `twitter_stream` thread(!).

When I wrote [Iodine](https://rubygems.org/gems/iodine) (a different server than Puma), I handled these use cases using the [`Iodine.run` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/iodine/0.2.16/Iodine#run-class_method), which defers tasks for later. The "saved" task should be performed only after the workers are initialized and the event loop starts running, so it's performed in each process (allowing you to start a new tread in each proccess).

i.e.

```
Iodine.run do
   Thread.start do
    twitter_stream.user do |object|
    # ...
    end
   end
end
```

I assume Puma has a similar solution. From what I understand of the [Puma Clustered-Mode Documentation](https://github.com/puma/puma#clustered-mode), Adding the following block to your `config/puma.rb` might help:

```
# config/puma.rb
on_worker_boot do
  Thread.start do
   twitter_stream.user do |object|
   # ...
   end
  end
end
```

Good luck!

---

**EDIT**: relating to the comment about `twitter_stream` using ActiveRecord

From the comments I gather that the `twitter_stream` callbacks store data in the DataBase as well as handle "push" events or notices.

Although these two concerns are connected, they are very different from each other.

For example, `twitter_stream` callbacks should only store data in the DataBase **once**. Even if your application grows to a billion users, you will only need to save the data in the database *once*.

This means that the `twitter_stream` callbacks should have their own dedicated process that runs only once, possibly separate from the main application.

At first, and as long as you limit your application to a single (only one server/application running), you might use `fork` together with the `initializer/twitter.rb` script... i.e.:

```
### START TWITTER PROCESS ### if production
if Rails.env.production?
  puts 'Starting Twitter Stream...'
  Process.fork do
    twitter_stream.user do |object|
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

On the other hand, **notifications** should be addressed to a specific user on a specific connection *owned* by a specific process.

Hence, notifications should be a separate concern from the `twitter_stream` DataBase update and they should be running in the background of every process, using the `on_worker_boot` (or `Iodine.run`) described above.

To achieve this, you might have `on_worker_boot` start a background thread that will listen to a pub/sub service such as Redis, while the `twitter_stream` callbacks "publish" updates to the pub/sub service.

This would allow each process to review the update and check if any of the connections it "owns" belongs to a client that should be notified of the update.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I have two workers, when I put my thread in the on_worker_boot block, the twitter stream starts twice. Is that okay? Will everything be duplicated in this case?

The handle_tweet method should only be called once, as it stores information in Active Record per tweet and potentially sends a direct message back to the user. If I need to use a whole other process (background app) for the twitter stream, do you have any pointers on how to get started with that?

Thanks for all of the help and sorry for my ignorance on the subject.

Comment: Hi @ToddSutter, thanks for the comment. I updated my answer to reflect the fat that the `twitter_stream` callbacks store data in the DataBase.

Comment: The extra information is extremely helpful. My twitter stream is basically a database interface so I will be trying to run a separate process like the Process.fork described above. I didn't know how to use or even what a separate process was so I'm glad I reached out! I will test this soon and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm reading your question, this doesn't look like an issue. A *sleeping* thread is different from a *dead* thread. Sleep just means that the thread is waiting idle, not consuming any cpu. If all else is hooked up properly, then as soon as the twitter api detects an event, it should wake the the thread up, run whatever handler you've defined, and then go right back to sleep. Sleeping isn't "running in the background," but it is "waiting for something to happen (e.g. someone tweets @me.) so I can run in the background."

A quick example to demonstrate this:

```
2.4.0 :001 > t = Thread.new { TCPServer.new(1234).accept ; puts "Got a connection! Dying..." }
 => #<Thread:0x007fa3941fed90@(irb):1 sleep> 
2.4.0 :002 > t
 => #<Thread:0x007fa3941fed90@(irb):1 sleep> 
2.4.0 :003 > t
 => #<Thread:0x007fa3941fed90@(irb):1 sleep> 
2.4.0 :004 > TCPSocket.new 'localhost', 1234
 => #<TCPSocket:fd 35> 
2.4.0 :005 > Got a connection! Dying...
t
 => #<Thread:0x007fa3941fed90@(irb):1 dead>
```

Sleeping just means "waiting for action."

---

Puma is a thread-based server, and is very particular about spinning threads up in its boot process, hence the warning about a thread started at app boot.

For what it's worth though, it's kind of weird to have a thread listening for updates from an api like that in a webserver. Maybe you should look into having a worker handle twitter events using something like [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque)? Or maybe [ActionCable](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) is relevant to your use case?

Comment: So would you suggest that I have another server run that only takes care of this twitter api, separate from my web server? I'm very new to all of this (if that wasn't obvious already). Or are these modules, Resque and ActionCable, plugins to my web server?

Comment: It really depends on exactly what your callbacks are doing. Are they communicating something back to the user? Are they saving records to the db? Are they doing something else entirely? Also important is how much time you're willing to invest in your app. Having, if not a second server, then at least a separate process handle these requests, is the more standard and rigorous way of doing things, since these callbacks aren't used for responding to an immediate request. From an architecture standpoint it's a bit more work, but it preempts questions like these by separating server/worker concerns

Comment: **Side-note**: Puma is **not** a thread-based server, rather, it's a reactor based server. Puma uses an event loop and a limited thread pool instead of the thread-based server design of a thread per connection. Puma also supports cluster mode (using processes for concurrency).

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Much appreciated! I do not need to respond the the user at all, it is more of a database interaction. It looks like I need to run a separate process to handle the twitter stream